# Container's height doesn't occupy the whole webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the container's height (with white background) to occupy the whole webpage, it was doing that.

I've forked my webpage and tried to replicate the bug, by commenting out and testing the code part by part. I'm fairly certain that when I used dl dd dt tags, it kinda broke the website. However, sometimes those tags break the design sometimes they doesn't. Can anyone take a look at the code, and explain to me what's going on and how to resolve it? Thanks.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="pad-left pad-top">
    <h2 class="title">Timeline</h2>
    <dl>
      <dt>June 28, 1971</dt>
      <dd>Elon Reeve Musk was born in Pretoria, Transvaal, South Africa, the son of Maye Musk and Errol Musk.</dd>
      .....
    </dl>

    <p class="text-center">To find out more about Elon Musk, visit <a href="https://blog.adioma.com/how-elon-musk-started-infographic/">How Elon Musk Started – Infographic</a></p>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pad-top { /* padding in header and on top of Timeline */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.pad-left { 
  padding-left: 30px;
}

dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 55px;
}

dt {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
}

dd {
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  padding-right:15px;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
}
```

https://codepen.io/jenlky/full/WZdQoB/

**EDIT:**

Problem solved. I changed the margin of footer from the default 16px to 0px, and ta-da it worked. I suppose the margin of the website's last element (be it footer or whatsoever) will affect it, so I have to take note.

Comment: Are you talking about the gap at the bottom of the white container?

Comment: Yes. I've solved the problem already with ZombieChowder's comment. I'm guessing the margin of the website's last element (be it footer or whatsoever) caused this to happen.

Comment: Cheers! So to avoid the footer text touching the bottom of the window, you may add something like padding-bottom: 10px; to the footer element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have a **margin** on your `p` element in the **footer**. Change the margin from `16 px` to `0` and it will fix it.

This is the element you need to change the margin of:

```
 <p>This page has been authored and coded by Jenssen Lee.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. When I commented out dl dt dd tags the problem still remained, I'm guessing the margin of the website's last element (be it footer or whatsoever) will affect it.

Comment: @helplah glad I could help.